# Remove Bottom border for tabed view react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to remove the border from tabed view for react native

[image]

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: Iam using this https://reactnavigation.org/

Comment: Iam using  indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff'}, for the yellow, I want to completely remove the border

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the borderBottomWidth property to 0

```
indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff', borderBottomWidth: 0 }
```

Comment: it is not working, showing warning "Failed prop type invalid prop.style key  borderBottom supplied to view"

Comment: Could you try borderBottomWidth: 0 instead?